# Format month/year in Ektron calendar header

Tags: ektron

Version 8.0.1 SP1

Our client would like us to reformat the month/year in the calendar header.  See attached image.  They want "April, 2012" instead of the abbreviated "Apr, 2012".  Where is this specified?  I have looked at the webcalendar objects, css files, xslt files.

Any suggestions?

[image: Example of the calendar header]

Comment: JQuery has been suggested also.  Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made that particular change, but have faced similar requests. Your options are-

- Use Javascript (jQuery) to reformat on client side
- Dig around in the workarea looking for formatting code, though usually the formatting code is locked up in a DLL.
- DisplayXslt or EkMarkup - some controls allow you to apply XSLT or EkMarkup (Ektron markup template) for custom display. You create an XSLT, and apply it via the DisplayXslt property on the control.
- Discard the control, and use the APIs to drive your own custom control.

Also, [this Ektron forum post](http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=34659) suggests having a look at this file- `workarea/webcalendar/xsl/default.xsl`
If this file exists (I don't have an Ektron installation currently handy), then it is likely you can use the DisplayXslt method described above.